# SmartGWT TabSet height in window

Tags: smartgwt

I'm trying to have a `TabSet` in a `Window`. I would like the window to fit the contents so I turned `autoSize` on like I have done with many other windows. The window have a minimum width and height that I want it to be. My problem is that the `TabSet` in the `Window` doesn't fill up the height completely.

Here is my setup:

```
public MyWindow()
{

  setHeight(MIN_HEIGHT);
  setWidth(MIN_WIDTH);

  setAutoSize(true);

  theTabSet = new TabSet();
  theTabSet.setTabBarPosition(Side.TOP);
  theTabSet.setWidth100();
  theTabSet.setHeight100();

  // I need to set this for it to at least display the contents
  theTabSet.setPaneContainerOverflow(Overflow.VISIBL E);
  theTabSet.setOverflow(Overflow.VISIBLE);

  //This seems to solve my issue buy I think I shouldn't be doing this.
  theTabSet.setMinHeight(WINDOW_HEIGHT);

  Tab tab1 = new Tab("first");
  tab1.setPane(getFirstTab());

  Tab tab2 = new Tab("second");
  tab2.setTab(getSecondTab());

  addItem(theTabSet);

 }

  private Layout getFirstTab(){
   if(theFirstTab == null){
     theFirstTab = new VLayout();
     theFirstTab.setWidth100();
     theFirstTab().setHeight100();
   }
     return theFirstTab;
 }
```

Please let me know if I am missing something. According to the [Layout](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/index.html) API:

> Like other Canvas subclasses, Layout and Stack components may have %
>   width and height values. To create a dynamically-resizing layout that
>   occupies the entire page (or entire parent component), set width and
>   height to "100%

Comment: did you try using setWidth("100%") instead of setWidth100()? it usually worked for me. the same for height

Comment: Yes. My problem was that I can't have the layout fill up the window if the window doesn't know its size until the components are drawn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
theTabSet.setMinHeight(WINDOW_HEIGHT);
```

Seems to be the way to go. The window is set to fit it contents and the layout is set to fill the canvas.  The window knows a minimum height and width but initially the layout doesn't know that. So we need to set it manually.